# Error loading SKTexture to device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

i've created an animation which works fine on the simulator, but when i use my device a big cross appear on the screen instead. i get following log message.

```
SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "Bird1"
```

i've double checked that all textures is in the bundle resources. How come it wont show on the device?

```
    SKTexture* birdTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Bird1"];
    birdTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

    SKTexture* birdTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Bird2"];
    birdTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    SKTexture* birdTexture3 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Bird3"];
    birdTexture3.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    SKTexture* birdTexture4 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Bird4"];
    birdTexture4.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    SKTexture* birdTexture5 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Bird5"];
    birdTexture5.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    SKTexture* birdTexture6 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Bird6"];
    birdTexture6.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    SKAction *flap = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[birdTexture1, birdTexture2, birdTexture3, birdTexture4, birdTexture5, birdTexture6] timePerFrame:0.15]];

    SKSpriteNode *mover = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:birdTexture1];
    [mover setScale:1.0];
    mover.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.size.height-120);

    [mover runAction:flap withKey:@"birdGo"];

    [self addChild:mover];
```

Comment: Refer the last answer here. It might be helpful at times.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431567/sktexture-error-loading-image-resource/31097576#31097576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried image file name with extension as like below?

```
SKTexture* birdTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Bird1.png"];
```

Otherwise try another methods as like below

```
SKTexture * texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rocket.png"]];
```

Comment: If you use `UIImage imageNamed:` you do not need the extension for png images.

Answer (score 5):

Try to cleaning your project: Product --> Clean. XCode caches image references when you test the project to speed compilation and this can lead to odd behaviors, especially if you change the names of images.

Answer (score 0):

Man, see if the resource's name isn't in different case, i don't know why, but in the simulator, if a resource's name is box.png and you just put Box.png, it works, but not on device, hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the correct path of the resource. It is good to use the full filename and extension as well.

Refer the last answer here:
[SKTexture: Error loading image resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431567/sktexture-error-loading-image-resource/31097576#31097576)