# SKTexture: Error loading image resource

Tags: ios, swift

This seems to work perfectly fine:

[image]

and when I created a new project with exactly the same thing, just new images, it doesn't work:

[image]

I even tried

```
var mainChartxt = SKTexture(imageNamed: "mainC.png")
```

and it still gives me the same error:

```
SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "img/mainC.png"
```

I tried cleaning the project and deleting the derived data folder and still no luck as the image doesn't show up on the app!

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where / How did you add the image in your project ?

The second syntax (without the *path*) should be ok. You don't even have to specify *.png* if that's the file format (but you need to if it something else : *.jpg*, *.jpeg*, ...

You might want to check that your asset is "checked" for the target membership. On the right side (Utilities) > File Inspector > Target Membership : *check* your target (not the tests one if you don't have any tests).

Comment: I just dragged and dropped it into the project >> ticked copy item if needed >>selected create folder references. 

There was only one thing that was checked in the Target Membership window which was a file by the name of the project's name. Is there anything else I can try? Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem specific to this particular image or it's the same with another ? Try to add the image to the .xcasset directly ?

Comment: Yep it was that image. Probably was corrupt or something. Thanks for the pointers :)

Answer (score 0):

A similar error occurred to me while following a tutorial to develop a game using spritekit.

Error was "SKTexture: Error loading image resource:"imagename""

In my case the path was not set properly.

We can recheck to be sure that the path is always set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is also possibility we select wrong destination device and we added asset to different device.

Added asset for Apple TV, but I was running app on iPhone. In this case also you will get same error.

So make sure destination device assets are added properly.

[image]